# Firebase transaction in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

What I try to achieve is simply increase a value in the database with a transaction. This is working for me as intended, but I always get following error in my firebase console:

```
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
```

My current call is as following:

```
exports.reportCounter = functions.database.ref('/user/{userId}/reports/{initiatorId}').onWrite((change,context) => {
const userId = context.params.userId;

return userRef.child(userId).child("numReports").transaction(function(numReports) {
    return change.after.exists()?((numReports || 0) + 1):(numReports - 1);
})
});
```

I also tried returning the promise directly:

```
return userRef.child(userId).child("numToIncrement").transaction(function(numToIncrement) {
            return ((numToIncrement || 0) + 1);
 });
```

In both cases, the code is doing what it is supposed to do, but I still receive said error.
[image]

Comment: You should be able to return the promise directly.  Please edit your question to show the *entire* code sample when you tried that.

Comment: I edited my post. I actually get another error when I try returning the promise directly, but this somehow seems to vary.

Comment: What do you mean "seems to vary"?

Comment: I sometimes get "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value", and sometimes I get "Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should implement the transaction, this way the function always returns a promise:

```
exports.reportCounter = functions.database.ref('/user/{userId}/reports/{initiatorId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  let increment;
  if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
    increment = 1;
  } else if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    increment = -1;
  }
  return userRef.child(userId).child("numReports").transaction(function(numReports) {
    return (numReports || 0) + increment;
  })
});
```

Comment: I still get "Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". I guess it has something to do with the fact, that transactions are being called more often than once in Firebase.